# is Map Constructor in js consumed more Ram than using import function in a large scale?

Tags: node.js

This is my first question so please try to understand what I am trying to say....My question is:-
If I use Map Constructor in a large scale or if I use dynamic import function for a large scale which will be more Ram consuming method
Actually I want to load js files from a folder.... I did it like this :-

```
async function action() {
  try {
    const moduleFolder = fs.readdirSync('./Commands');

    for (const folder of moduleFolder) {
      const moduleFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./Commands/${folder}`);

      for (const SecondFolder of moduleFiles) {
        const secondFolder = fs.readdirSync(`./Commands/${folder}/${SecondFolder}`);

        for (const file of secondFolder) {
          const modulePath = `./../Commands/${folder}/${SecondFolder}/${file}`;

          if (file.endsWith('.js')) {
            const module = await import(modulePath);
            cmd = module.default.name;
            alias = module.default.alias;
            let aliasInclude = alias.map((a) => a.startsWith(cmdName) ? true : false)

            if (cmd === cmdName || aliasInclude.includes(true)) {
              await react(module.default.react || "")

              return await module.default.run(Neko, m.messages[0], {
                mentionTag,
                name,
                sender,
                gcMeta,
                gcName,
                args,
                from,
                cmdName,
                body,
                quoted,
                text,
                viewonce,
                isGroup,
                isQuoted,
                isMe,
                messageType,
                fetchF,
                Admins,
                isMeAdmin,
                isAdmin,
                GroupDb,
                UserDb,
                isOwner,
                groupId,
                participants
              })
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    await react("")

    return m.messages[0].reply("text", null, "*_No Such Command Exists!!_*");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error importing modules:', error);
  }
}

await action();
```

Is it good or I should load all files from the beginning using map constructor and when ever name is called I will run

Please tell me which will be more efficient....thank yo
u!